# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]| [c++]

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the following code on Ubuntu (64-bit), with Code::Blocks 10.05 as IDE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char a[2];
    cout << "enter ab ";
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 'ab') // line 7
    {
         cout << "correct";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On line 7, my compiler gives me the error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]".

Why doesn't this work?  I know I could use an `std::string` to work around the problem, but I want to understand the current problem.

Comment: note that `'ab'` is an int, whereas `"ab"` is an array of chars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer \[-fpermissive\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589111/iso-c-forbids-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer-fpermissive)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`char a[2]` defines an array of `char`'s. `a` is a pointer to the memory at the beginning of the array and using `==` won't actually compare the contents of `a` with `'ab'` because they aren't actually the same types, `'ab'` is integer type. Also `'ab'` should be `"ab"` otherwise you'll have problems here too. To compare arrays of char you'd want to use strcmp.

Something that might be illustrative is looking at the `typeid` of `'ab'`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int some_int =5;
    std::cout << typeid('ab').name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(some_int).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

on my system this returns:

```
i
i
```

showing that `'ab'` is actually evaluated as an int.

If you were to do the same thing with a std::string then you would be dealing with a class and std::string has `operator ==` overloaded and will do a comparison check when called this way.

If you wish to compare the input with the string "ab" in an idiomatic c++ way I suggest you do it like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string a;
    cout<<"enter ab ";
    cin>>a;
    if(a=="ab"){
         cout<<"correct";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not quite correct (`a` is an array, as you could see with `sizeof(a)`), and not the actual problem.

Comment: I think I said that, I think the formatting is a bit confusing here.

Comment: I thought there is no difference between char a[13124]; and string a;

Comment: @İbrahimYazıcı: a std::string is actually a class that contains a string. The benefits of using a std::string include not needing to worry so much about the internal representation or the memory management of the underlying data. This makes it easier to write error free code and also helps you be more productive as you don't have to spend as much time worrying about mundane details.

Answer (score 12):

This one is due to:

`if(a=='ab')` , here,  `a` is `const char*` type (ie : array of char)

`'ab'` is a constant value,which isn't evaluated as string (because of single quote) but will be evaluated as integer.

Since `char` is a primitive type inherited from C, no operator  `==` is defined.

the good code should be:

`if(strcmp(a,"ab")==0)` , then you'll compare a `const char*` to another `const char*` using `strcmp`.

Comment: Unless there's been undefined behavior, `strcmp( a, "ab" )` cannot return `0`.  `a` has type `char[2]`, so the longest C style string it can contain is 1 character.  Anything more, and you've got undefined behavior.

Comment: indeed,a should be at least 3 char long for it to be able to contain final NUL char of string.However, compiler alignment for storing this 2 bytes array may result in 0 filling the adjacent 2 bytes memory of the a variable, thus , making the code "working" despite  the programmer's error.

Comment: Padding may save you here.  Until the user leans on the space key before doing his input.  First rule of input: expect anything, even if its not reasonable.  (And the second is always to allow leading and trailing white space.  People do accidentally hit the space key from time to time, and if it's at the beginning or the end, they don't see it.)

Answer (score 6):

In DEVC++, I faced same issue and i got solution.
I used single quote instead of double quote.

Answer (score -2):

In your code,you wrote char a[2]; which is wrong.You shoud've wrote char* a[2]; Then you can get your proper output.