# c++ forbids comparsion between pointer and integer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]| [c++]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280921/iso-c-forbids-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer-fpermissive-c)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char name[20];
char color[20];
char response[20];
int age;
    cout << "What is your name?\n";
    cin.getline(name, 20); cout << endl;
    cout << "What is your favorite color?\n";
    cin.getline(color, 20); cout << endl;
    cout << "How old are you?\n";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Your name is " << name << ", your favorite color is " << color << " and you are " << age << " years old!\n";
    cin.get();
    cout << "You wake up from bed all you know is your name and age.\n";
    cout << "You are wearing a plain " << color << " t-shirt.\n";
    cout << "You see a gun on the table.\n";
    cout << "You see a door.\n";
    cout << "What do you do?\n";
    cin.getline(response, 20);
    if(response == 'Pick up the gun')
    {
        cout << "You pick up the gun.\n";
        cout << "Knock down the door with it? (Y/N)\n";
        cin.getline(response, 20);
        if(response == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "The door opens.\n";
            cout << "You see a zombie.\n";
            cout << "You see an open window.\n";
            cout << "What do you do?\n";
            cin.getline(response, 20);
            if(response == 'Shoot the zombie')
            {
                cout << "The zombie dies and it attracts other zombies.\n";
                cout << "GAME OVER!\n";
                cin.get();
                return 0;
            }
            else if(response == 'Jump out the window')
            {
                cout << "The zombie does not hear you and you safely make it out!\n";
                cout << "VICTORY!\n";
                cin.get();
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else if(response == 'N')
        {
        }
    }
    else if(response == 'Open the door')
    {
        cout << "It appears to be locked.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

trying to make a super ultra short and simple text rping game but it does not work!
my errors are:

> ```
> 24 error:no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(std::string&)'
> ```

and also on EVERY SINGLE LINE with the response `if` stuff i get
C++ forbids comparsion between pointer and integer

im not trying to do that in any way shape or form o_o
nothing seems to help solve it. people seem to get it to work because they use `""` instead of `''` and they change it to `''` and it works fine. but im always using `''`!

Comment: Seriously, just use `std::string`. Even if you use the right kind of literal, it's still wrong.

Comment: Also you cannot use `'` for string literals. `'a'` represents _char literal a_, while `"a"` represents _string a_.

Comment: The first thing you should do is build a program that only demonstrates the problem.  Copy pasting an entire program is not polite.  Couldn't you demonstrate this error in a 3 line program?

Answer (score 3):

For the if statements, you should be using:

```
if(strcmp(response,"Pick up the gun"))
```

But in reality, all of your problems will be made much easier if you use `std::string`

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string name;
  string response;
  getline(cin, response);
  if !(response.compare("Pick up the gun"))
  {
    //Do stuff here for picking up gun
  }
}
```

Comment: this USED to work when i did 'y' or 'n' but now it doesent. idk what i did different here.

Comment: strcmp was not declared in this scope :(

Comment: You would need a `#include <stdio.h>`. But see my latest edit, it's really much better.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto, You probably meant to say `<cstring>`.

Comment: `cin::getline` has no overload for `std::string`. Use `std::getline(std::cin, string);`

Comment: the response.compare i don't know how to trigger something when it happens. you are using a ; at the end which means it can't be an if or an else if.

Comment: @RonanZer0, With `std::string`, `if (response == "Pick up the gun")` works fine.

Comment: 25 error:no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(std::string&)'

Comment: That's what I get for going off of memory... Need to specify a line size estimate with getline, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Comment: @RonanZer0, noew it should work

Comment: lol4t0 what did you edit? and  @Pearsonartphoto how do i specify a line size? i don't see on the page.

Comment: @RonanZer0, I wrote it 2 times already: "cin::getline has no overload for std::string. Use std::getline(std::cin, string);". You cannot write `cin.getline(string)`, but should `getline(cin, string)`

Answer (score 2):

Just use strcmp, read about arrays and dereferencing, and know that 'A' denotes the ASCI uppercase A where "A" denotes a string ie ['A','null'].

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: cant. not declared in this scope.