# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, iso

**The Code**

```
int cycle_length(int i, int j) {
    int cycleLength = 0;
    for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
        cout << algorithm(k) << endl;
        if (algorithm(k) > cycle_length) {
            cycleLength = algorithm(k);
        }
    }
    return cycleLength;
}
```

`ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]`

I got this error in this line `if ( algorithm(k) > cycle_length)`.

How is that, however, the same code works right in the `main()` ?? and what is this error mean ???

**Added**
algorithm is a function take an integer input and return an integer.

```
int algorithm(int number1) {
    int counter = 1, number = number1;
    do {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            number = number / 2;
            counter++;
        } else {
            number = (3 * number) + 1;
            counter++;
        }
    } while (number != 1);

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: How is `algorithm` defined?

Comment: algorithm(k) return a pointer? Do you have others algorithm()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing the name of the function with your local variable of nearly the same name:

```
int cycle_length(int i, int j)
{
    int cycleLength
```

Your function is called `cycle_length`, your variable is called `cycleLength` - yet you are using `cycle_length` further down.

The error message is slightly strange, because the compiler doesn't do "compare variable names with function names to see if there is one that is similar and then suggest that maybe you just typed it wrong" - it simply says "Hmm, you are comparing a function pointer [what you get from the name of a function] with an integer, that's not on!"

Comment: `clang` might make a better suggestion.  Let me try it out here.

Comment: It didn't make a better suggestion, but the error message contains the types, so you can tell that you're comparing with a function pointer.  That's still better than gcc, but not as good as trying to correct the typo would be.  Message: `excpp.cpp:13:27: error: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'int (*)(int, int)')`  Another good reason to use `clang`!

Comment: I've noticed that clang tends to give slightly more verbose error messages in general [which can be somewhat annoying, when you have many errors, because the first one scrolls off the screen before you've seen it...]

Comment: Well, MOST of the time I'm not having a problem with it - but sometimes you have one of those situations where some missing/extra character causes a lot of errors... [Missing semicolon in header file is a favourite for this].

Comment: Right, but clang gives *much* better errors in the semicolon case than gcc does.  Including a suggestion of just where to put it.  A little bit of scrolling is definitely worth it in that case, and particular for beginners.

Comment: Hmm, don't think I've hit that particular one in clang - I was more referring tot he tendency to produce several lines for one error, which when you get lots of them (say, you forgot to include <string>, and thus get a complaint for every usage of string and possibly other errors because it got lost), even the scrollback buffer isn't long enough sometimes (yes, I can set longer scrollback buffer). Either way, we've diverged quite a bit...